# Not able to identify duplicate value in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-loop

Hi I have input(inside ngFor, so same input field created with length of my array) in my HTML and binding to my ngModel and i have ngModelChange function as below:

```
 onChangeReference(value: any, account: any, option: any) {
        // this.referenceArray = Object.keys(this.your_reference).map(key => this.your_reference[key]);
        console.log(this.referenceArray, value, 'huhu');
        let tmpReference:Array<any> = [];
        if (value) {
            if (_.includes(this.referenceArray, value)) {
                console.log('item und');
                option.isRefDuplicate = true;
                // this.referenceArray.pop();
            } else {
                console.log('item illa');
                this.referenceArray.push(value);
                option.isRefDuplicate = false;
            }
        }
}
```

Basically what i need to achieve is if there is any duplicated value in this.your_reference Array, i need to show error below that particular input field. I could able to achive it 90%, but now the problem is if enter "aaa" in one input field, and in other input field i key in the same value "aaa", working fine. showing error message. But when i backspace and remove one value its actually a new value "aa" which shouldnt be in my this.your_reference array. But it still showing error. How to fix this guys. Any idea?

Comment: You filled your question with so many unnecessary details, when it should be minimal and straight-forward.

Comment: sorry, just want to be more descriptive